# Are the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and the existence of limit superior and limit inferior independent?

Tags: real-analysis

I mean can we prove one with the help of the other? Or do we need some more statements?

Comment: Both proofs rely upon the same monotonic convergence theorem. Did you read the proofs?

Comment: I had seen a proof of the Bolzano-Weistrauss Theorem by the Nested Invervals. And I have proved the existence of Sup/Inf limits by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Take a look at Ross' book on real analysis: He proves BW by constructing a monotonic subsequence.

Comment: Also: Both theorems are equivalent to the completeness axiom.

Comment: What do you mean by _superior_ (or _inferior_) _limit_ ?

Comment: @studiosus: what do you mean by _completeness axiom_ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior
And  I think Comleteness axiom means is the assumption of the Least Upper Bound.

Comment: If you read well your link, you find that the superior/inferior limits always exist ... Surely you meant suprema/infima (or least upper bounds/greatest lower bounds). For the question, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Bolzano.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: @Stefan H.: what do you mean by limit superior/inferior ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: [Limit superior and limit inferior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior)

Comment: @Stefan H.: read my last comment to the O.P.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: But Grobber himself commented that he is referring to limit superior/inferior.

Comment: @Stefan H.: the problem is that O.P. doesn't give a new definition of limsup/liminf as one must do if she/he has not the lub/glb at disposal. See **studiosus**'s answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the clear the confusion in the comments, here is the answer. I left few details out, if you want to see more details, let me know.

Theorem. Suppose that $F$ is an ordered field. Then the following are equivalent:

i. $F$ satisfies BW (Bolzano-Weiserstrass) theorem.

ii. Every bounded sequence in $F$ has limit superior.

Proof. First, we need to define $\lim\sup$ (and $\lim\inf$), provided they exist, without resorting to using $\sup$ and $\inf$ as it is usually done as we do not have the completeness Axiom at our disposal. Here is one way to do so:

Given a sequence $(x_n)$ consider the set $A$ of limits of subsequences in $(x_n)$. If there exists the maximal element $a$ of the set $A$ then we say that 
$$
a=\lim\sup x_n.
$$
If such maximal element does not exist, we will say that $\lim\sup$ does not exist. Define $\lim\inf$ similarly. It is not hard to see that this definition agrees with the usual one provided that $F$ satisfies the Completeness Axiom. 
(I think, it is in the Ross' book.)

a. Suppose first that $F$ satisfies the limsup property; then it is easy to see that it also satisfies property the "liminf property": Every bounded sequence has $\lim\inf$. Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $F$. It is proven e.g. in Ross' "Real Analysis" that every ordered field satisfies the property:

Every sequence contains a monotonic subsequence.

Thus, let $(x_{n_k})$ be a monotonic subsequence in $(x_n)$. Then $(y_k)=(x_{n_k})$ is clearly bounded. If $(y_k)$ is increasing then it is again easy to see that its $\lim\sup$ (which exists) equals its ordinary limit; if it is decreasing, then its $\lim\inf$ (which exists) equals the ordinary limit. In either case, $(x_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence.

b. Suppose that $F$ satisfies the Bolzano-Weierstrass property and let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $F$. Consider the set $A$ defined above. By BW property, $A$ is nonempty. It is also clear that $A$ is bounded above. If $A$ has maximal element, we are done. Suppose that a maximal element does not exist.

It is again not hard to see that there exist a strictly increasing sequence $(a_k)$ in $A$ with the property:

(*) For every $a\in A$ there exists $k$ so that 
$a<a_k$.

Let $b$ denote a limit of a subsequence in $(a_n)$ which exists by BW property. By monotonicity, it follows that $b=\lim_n a_n$. By using the standard "diagonal" argument, one sees that $b\in A$. It is also clear (from the definition of the limit) that $a_k<b$ for all $k$.

By our assumption, $b$ is not a maximal element of $A$. Then there exists $a\in A$ such that $b<a$. By Property (*), there exists $a_k$ so that  $a<a_k$. However, $a_k<b<a<a_k$. Contradiction. qed

One can also prove that Completeness Axiom is equivalent to (i) and (ii) but I will skip this.

Edit: The last sentence was wrong as written: You need to assume in addition that the field $F$ is *Archimedean", that is, the semigroup of natural numbers "naturally" (pun intended) embedded in $F$, is unbounded. Otherwise, I think, the ordered field(s) of *nonstandard real numbers* provide counter-example(s). One needs the *Axiom of Choice* to construct these, so maybe there are some interesting foundational issues here.

Comment: If O.P. doesn't give a new definition of limsup/liminf (as you have done), the question doesn't make sense. There is chaos, not confusion !

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: You have an excellent point here (I do not think OP realized that this is a problem), but I tried to make as much sense of the question as I could. I hope, both chaos and confusion are cleared now, if not - let me know! There are other, equivalent, definitions of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ in the literature which avoid using the word "supremum" and "infimum". I never likes those, but now I understand why they bother giving nonstandard definitions. See e.g. "Real Analysis" (2nd Edition), A. M. Bruckner, J. B. Bruckner, and B. S. Thomson.

Comment: Thank you fo the reference. To me the matter has been perfectly cleared: congratulations again for the professional proof (the edit is very interesting).

Comment: I am really sorry for the chaos I have initiated. I am a layman in terms of Analysis and don't have got a clear grip on it.

Comment: Another silly question. What's $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}(-n)$?

Comment: @Grobber: It is $-\infty$. I corrected the statement to reflect the fact that the sequence has to be bounded (not just bounded above).